# Inheritance of types in generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Why does following C# code produces an error:

> CS0030: Cannot convert type `'Test.G<Test.C>'` to `'Test.G<Test.I>'`

```
interface I { }
class C : I { }
class G<T> { }

class B {
    G<C> a = new G<C>();

    void Test() {
        G<I> v = (G<I>)a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier help?

Comment: Go read up on C# covariance, that's why you can't do this.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me to the right topic. I obviously could not find the right words when googling the problem.

Comment: Just for your information. As I could not change the variance of the parenting interface (coming from 3rd part API) I ended up using not so elegant but effective method using dynamic.